# How to get search of different location?

Tags: google-maps, google-search

On android device, whatever we do Google search, we get search content of nearby location.

- Is it possible to get search content of another location?
- If yes, what I need to do in my android device?

Regards
GNS

Comment: Google supports "other nearby location" partially by adding a keyword "near `LocationName`" (e.g. "Hotel *near O'Hare airport*"). Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You can use applications like [FakeGPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en).

Using which you can mock your device's location. Hope this helps you

Comment: Will Fake GPS affect other features and services related to locations? Using Fake GPS, may I get search content of desired location? If it'll affect all features and services related to locations, can it be turned off also?

Comment: It's just mocks your location so the device doesn't have to be physically present at that location. Once you are done you can simply close the app so your device again fetched your current location.